# Physical effects of homogenization method?

Tags: density, material-science

I'm reading a text on [shape optimization by homogenization method](http://www.cmap.polytechnique.fr/~jouve/papers/euroef.pdf).

Here the author writes that it may be impossible to find a minimum for the objective function $E(\omega)$ minimizing compliance and weight. And that

> The physical reason for this non-existence is that it is often advantageous to cut infinitely many small holes (rather than just a few big ones) in a given design in order to decrease $E(\omega)$.

and

> Thus, achieving the minimum may require a limiting procedure leading to a “generalized” design consisting of composite materials made by microperforation.

I'd like to understand, how is this interpreted in physical material? I.e. how do the above quotes make sense?

Comment: sorry, I think your link is broken